# I'd like to know how to write $x^4$ with ladder operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

I'm doing an exercise where I have to use the time-independent perturbative method. In this particular situation, I'm perturbating the ground state of a 1D harmonic oscillator with a perturbation proportional to $x^4$. Do you know how can I write it with Ladders Operators?

Comment: Do you know the expression of the operator $\hat x$ in terms of $\hat a$ and $\hat a^+$? Then, you just have to take the fourth power.

Comment: Yes i know it! But i get lost when i have to do moltiplications between operators, my coefficients doesn't match with the right answer

Comment: Did you commute $a$ and *a^\dagger$ properly? Show your work!